# $_POST doesnt receive data from input text using tag form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, null

I have problems sending the value from my input text to my variable(**$name**) in my php code:

Here I send my data to edit.php

```
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="edit_text"/>
    <input id="send" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

my edit.php file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$name = isset($_POST["edit_text"])?$_POST["edit_text"]:"";
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","example");
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = '".$name."'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($row);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I am looking for a record in my table, then I return a json object with the values of my query. But it only works If I put the name of my item directly in the string:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = 'ITEM'");
```

I use getjson and console.log() to see what happens and it returns the json object with the correct values from my table.

But if I use the same query but with my variable **$name** that has assigned the same name of my item concatenated to the query doesnt work.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = '".$name."'");
```

It always returns null values as if nothing is assigned to my **$name** variable from my input text.

Comment: what kind of header it is? `header("Content-Type: application/jason");` should be `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: is this some ajax post? did you tried print_r($_POST)?

Comment: Fix `jason` to `json`.

Comment: Check the error from mysqli with mysqli_errno and mysqli_error

Comment: hahaha I didnt see that, thank you for answer but I changed jason to json in the header but nothing changed.

Comment: So if we post edit_text with a value like: "1'; drop table items; select '" what do you think will happen?.. Suggestion: read into sql injection. (and check out mysqli prepare..)

Comment: addendum to @DamienOvereem's comment: you're directly inputting your form's input into your query (`$name`, in this case). This makes your query very vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: thank you so much for the advices, I didnt know about sql injection I will definitely take a look at it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change your code to something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_text'])) {

    $name = $_POST['edit_text'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","example");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM items WHERE name = '$name'");

    $data = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                                       // Noitcie ^ the 'I' here
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Also, if you're using double quotes you don't need to concatenate your variables.

Hope this helps!

Comment: One thing I would look into though is escape your variables as this is vulnerable to sql injection. A place to start would be either http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php or look on youtube for stuff on PDO.